# On convergence of a series of expectations given almost sure convergence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $\{ X_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a positive valued stochastic process that converges almost surely to an integrable random variable $X_{\infty}$ then is it true that

$$ -\infty < \sum_{n= 1}^{\infty} E[ X_{n+1} - X_n | X^n  ] < \infty $$

where $X^n= \{ X_n, X_{n-1}, \dots, X_1 \}$.  I know that almost sure convergence does not guarantee convergence in mean but I believe this statement is being used in a proof I am trying to understand, is it true?

EDIT: as pointed out by Marcus M, there are trivial counterexamples if some bounds on the means is not assumed. So I would add the assumption that $E[ X_{n+1} | X^n  ]  < \infty \ \forall{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $E[X_1] < \infty$ to keep the question relevant.

Comment: Try an example where $X_n$ are integrable, $E[X_n] \to \infty$ rapidly, and $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.  It's easy to construct such examples on the probability space $[0,1]$.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think I see what you mean. Is only the left hand side inequality true then?  that it does not diverge to $- \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can come up with a super basic that breaks this: let $X_1$ be any random variable with $E[X_1] = +\infty$, and let $X_j = 1$ for all $j \geq 2$.

Comment: Very nice counterexample, maybe I should add the condition that the $X_n$ all have finite mean to keep the question interesting.